# NODE.JS wont listen on Debian Webserver

Tags: javascript, node.js, debian, node.js-connect

I have a Debian 6 server that runs several domains.

I have created a new domain (that functions perfectly as a website), but I want to create a node.js scripts that listens on that domain.

Doesn't have to be a specific port, it can be the entire domain as far as I am concerned, but for simplicity I am trying to test on port3000

The directory structure is

domainname/public/(static content)

I am running the node at the domainname/ level.. i.e one level below the webcontent. I have a test index.html file in the public folder (which works fine). The test script is

```
var connect = require('connect');

var app = connect()
    .use(connect.static('public'))
    .use(function (req, res) {
        res.end("Couldn't find it.");
    })
    .listen(3000);
```

the script runs but going to

```
http://domainname:3000
```

just throws me a page cannot be found error.

Any advice would be gratefully appreciated. Either a script change, or a different module maybe

Comment: Is port 3000 open on your server?

Comment: You may be on the right track.. when I did (on the server) a wget http://domainname:3000 it did download the index.html file.

I added port 3000 to the iptables but it made no difference. Maybe the script is only listening locally...

Comment: I'd advise to use something like Express.  It makes node so much simpler to use.  Then just check out EJS or Jade as a template engine for Express.  I personally use EJS because no page designer I work with will hand over page designs in Jade's 'compressed' format, only HTML.

Comment: I am not actually using the node to act as a proper webserver, more to query and dish up JSON data on request by an angular.js app I am writing. I can make it all work locally, I am now just trying to implement the node on a proper server and its just not playing ball. I will look into this potential port problem.

Comment: I think I tried with the express modules as well.. they cant both be broken, more evidence of a server issue maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, there was too much going on with regards to the server which was already a full functional website.

I ended up creating an EC2 micro instance on AWS, installing NODE afresh, opening up the required port and uploading my code and BOOM worked first time.

Thanks for all those taking time to offer an answer